# VBA not able to fill all FNODE and TNODE because of large number (1,200,000) of records?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, vba

I need to populate FNODE and TNODE fields for my roads dataset.

I have an intersections point feature class that has unique ids, and I need each road segment to have an FNODE and TNODE value that corresponds to the intersection id.

The roads are broken into segments at each intersection so that each segment only touches 2 intersection points.

I thought that maybe Network Analyst generated these, but it doesn't look like it actually writes these values.

Does anyone know how to generate these?

In addition, I have used the VBA code but because of its large records(1,200,000 records), VBA is not able to fill all the FNODE and TNODE.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091

Comment: You may want to edit your question to focus it a bit more. Right now it seems like you're asking two questions - how do I fix this VBA code, or how do I generate to/from node attributes. Is [this the VBA code in question](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/72291)? From what I know, that kind of node info can be generated with the legacy coverage format and using Geometric Network tools, but there isn't a tool that is part of Network Analyst that does this.

Comment: Dear Chris, could you please give me your E-mail for sending more details of my problem?

Comment: @cristianotoorani Sorry, GIS.SE doesn't really work like that. It's best if you edit your question to incorporate the additional details. You can include screenshots and links, as well as pasting sections of code if needed. Once the question is edited it is automatically nominated for reopening, and votes or a mod can do so or provide additional comment for improvement/clarification.

Comment: Can I do the sql server for find fnode and tnode?