# Query limited to 1000 features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, arc-hydro

I was working in ArcHydro 9 and ArcGIS 9.3. I have a street network and I was populating From_Node and To_Node columns in Attribute Table using ArcHydro 9 Attribute Tools tab. However only 1000 arc FIDs got populated in my ArcMap. Rest From_Node and To-node was populated null.

I have seen in Stack Exchange group someone referred to editing MaxRecordCount, but I can't locate it. Neither could I locate the path in Program Files\ArcGIS\server\user\cfg.
Can any one help?

Comment: The MaxRecordCount is for ArcGIS server, and not ArcGIS Desktop. And 9.3 is a pretty old software. It was released in 2008. Can you use a more up-to-date software?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=MaxRecordCount

Comment: If you'd like to pursue this question and its current direction of 'why is this tool getting stuck at 1k records' I would suggest editing the question to remove the maxrecordcount reference and provide more details about your data (run a geometry check on it?). If you want to pursue alternative means of generating the to/from node attributes, take a look at Hornbydd's solution or the question I linked to as a comment on that answer (which also links to other questions, including an earlier one of yours on the topic).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to process a street network with a tool designed for processing hydrological data? Hmmm...

If you are just interested in extracting nodes then have you searched arcscripts? There are numerous tools that you can download for free created by the user community. ArcScripts was "frozen in time" a few years ago when they turned off that website to force people to use the utterly unusable gallery on ArcGIS.com...

So many of the tools on ArcScripts are suitable for ArcGIS 9.3, have a look [here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/scripts.asp?pg=1&sb=1&ob=asc&eDate=&n=&top=&eLang=&eProd=28&perPage=10&eQuery=node&Submit2=search).

Comment: I think Devdatta Tengshe is right. MaxRecordCount is for ArcGIS Server and I have ArcGIS Desktop. That is the reason I could not locate it.   I am using ArcHydro to create From_Nodes and To_Nodes because I do not have any tool in Network Analyst to do the job. And ArcHydro is getting stuck at 1000 features.

Comment: It would help if Hornbydd can tell me any other tool which can create To_Nodes/From_nodes from a street network?

Comment: Hornbydd, I have gone through your link. Unfortunately none seems to work with ArcGIS 9.3..............

Comment: @KoushikPaul see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/