# Updating from and to junctions for the road segments in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I have road line and junction point with me, I would like to know how to update the from and to junction ids to the road segment based on the road digitization direction.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! Regarding your question, is there any way you can elaborate on what you need just a little more? Can you attach a screenshot of what you're working with? Are you needing the steps to edit the road ranges in your data?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091