# How to select only the lines that has points at at least one end?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, select-by-location

I have 2 separate feature classes, line and point. I want to select line feature class based on the location of points on a point feature class. If the points are on the line itself then I don't want to select the line. But, if they are at its end/start, the line should be selected.

Comment: You can export the Line endpoints to a Point featureclass - "Feature Vertices to Points", select Point type = "END". Use this in your select by location, join the results back to the lines on Objectid or Fid.

Comment: Assign point IDs to line, using something like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091

Comment: I already have a points feature class. I need to select the lines based on that point feature class.
I did what you said, it will select all the lines as all the lines now have points at its ends (got using "Feature Vertices to points")

Comment: You need to @ user name, otherwise you are messaging to a void

Comment: You completely misunderstood what @klewis suggesting. Perhaps read again

Comment: @klewis I have clarified the question. If you suggest the same thing, can you be more descriptive?

Comment: @felixIP Thank you!! I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest these steps to Select Lines that Intersect another Point FC only at Line End Points.

Export the Line endpoints to a Point featureclass (named Line_endpoints) - "Feature Vertices to Points", select Point type = "END".

Select By Location, Line_endpoints with Point_FC, Intersect. You can add a small Search Tolerance if needed (if Points don't match exactly)

Select By Location, Line FC with Line_endpoints, Intersect, click Use Select features

Comment: +1 I posted explanation of your solution and saw your answer. oops

Comment: @FelixIP, no problem. Your answer is more descriptive with graphics.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you can solve this by using [`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) on your point feature class and load the point geometry into a list. In a `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` the geometry object can be accessed via the `SHAPE@` token. Something like this:

```
point_feature_class = r'C:\path_to_data\points.shp'
points = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(point_feature_class, "SHAPE@") as s_cur:
    for row in s_cur:
        points.append(row[0])
```

Then you can again use an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` to loop over the line features and compare the first and last points of the lines to the points within the list you created above. Something like this:

```
line_feature_class = r'C:\path_to_data\lines.shp'
lines_to_select = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_feature_class, ['OID@', 'SHAPE@"]) as s_cur:
    for row in s_cur:
        first_point = row[1].firstPoint
        last_point = row[1].lastPoint
        for pt in points:
            if pt == first_point or pt == last_point:
                lines_to_select.append(row[0])
```

This will give you a list of OID of lines that have points from the point feature class that are either the first or last point. You can then use the OID values within your list in many or one complex [`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm).

This is off the top of my head and is a fairly roundabout way to get this done, but it should get the job done and/or get you going in the right direction. One note about this method is because you are comparing geometries, you need to make sure that that both feature classes have or don't have `Z` and `M` values. If one does and the other does not then this process should be modified to just compare the `XY` values either through straight comparisons or creating new more simple point geometries of just `XY`. There is certainly room for improvements and simplifications of this process.

Comment: Your `line_feature_class` is the same shapefile as the `point_feature_class'. I don't think you meant to do that.

Comment: @Fezter thanks for the heads up, I made the corrections. Copy and paste is not always the best when quickly coding...

Comment: I strongly believe that scripting should be your last resource, esp. for tasks that unlikely to be repeated

Comment: @FelixIP personal preference. Many tools to solve problems in GIS. For someone with the skill set I would go the other route as scripts can be automated if the task is repeated often. But I see your point :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is what @klewis suggesting:

[image]

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("LINES", "D:/Scratch/ends.shp", " BOTH_ENDS ")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ends", "INTERSECT", "POINTS")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ends", "SWITCH_SELECTION")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(in_features="ends")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("LINES", "FID", "ends", "ORIG_FID", "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("LINES", "NEW_SELECTION", """"ends.ORIG_FID" IS NOT NULL""")
```

[image]