# Connected nodes and lines in a pipe network

Tags: qgis, network

I'm relatively new to GIS. I'm currently using QGIS.

I have 2 shapesfiles for a sanitary pipe network - a manhole file with the manhole nodes, and a pipe file with the pipe lines.

I need to find a way to identify the nodes which a line is "connected" to.

ie: Pipe ID *n* is connected to Manhole IDs *x* and *y*

Comment: Try looking at the attribute data for each shapefile. There should be a field  in the manhole shapefile that tells you to which pipeline each manhole corresponds. If it's not clear to you how to figure this out, add a screenshot of each attribute table to your question and we may be able to help.

Comment: Arcgis solution easy to adjust    http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091

Comment: @csk it is usually other way around, pipe has up upstream and downstream manholes

Comment: @FelixIP is correct, I'm trying to determine the upstream and downstream manholes connected to the pipe (line feature).  The link you included sounds like what I thought I may have to do, but being a GIS beginner, I just wasn't sure how to go about it.  Thanks for the help.