# Auto-populate "from" and "to" attribute fields of line layer with Unique IDs of points from point layer?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, points-to-line, unique-id

I have a line layer where each line segment is snapped to 2 of the points from our point layer in QGIS.  Each point has a Unique ID which I need to carry over automatically to a "from_point" field and a "to_point" field in the line layer attribute table.

Would there be a way to populate the fields after digitizing all the lines and points?

I figure we will need to run some sort of spatial query to relate the 2 points to each line segment and then run some sort of expression to populate the fields.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091