# How to summarize overlapping polygon values within a single layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features, arcgis-10.5, summarizing

At ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, I have a polygon file geodatabase feature class.  Many of its polygons are spatially coincident; that is, if I click on a single polygon in Arcmap to select it, the resulting selection will have multiple records, all sharing the same exact polygon outline.  Here's a screenshot example where one polygon is selected, resulting in 74 selected records.  In my mind, they represent 74 polygons stacked upon each other.

[image]

The attribute table contains a long integer field, noise_value.  I need to sum this field for each input polygon, which, as I mentioned above, may be comprised of multiple spatially coincident polygons, and output the result to a new, flattened, polygon feature class containing the summed value.

In my example, the 74 overlapping polygons would be reduced to a single output polygon with a summed noise_value.  Of course, this summation would have to be repeated for all input polygons.

I've tried these approaches, and all have failed:

**1. Flatten the input feature class while applying the field map merge rule "SUM" for the noise_value attribute.**

I tried this approach with the *Feature Class to Feature Class* tool as well as the *Merge* tool.  In each case the output was identical to the input; no flattening or summing occurred.

**2. Create a flattened output feature class and then spatially join it to the original feature class, summing by noise_value with field map merge rule SUM.**

I tried this approach with the *Feature to Polygon* tool, and also with the *Union* tool to create the flattened output feature class.  Both cases failed, with a "Topoengine error".  Research indicates that this type of error can be traced to inadequate hardware resources, but I'm using a computer with an i7 processor, 16GB ram and a 1 TB SSD.

**3. Use the *Dissolve* tool (@BERA's suggestion) with noise_value as the statistics field and Statistics Type = SUM.**

Since what I want to do is flatten (dissolve) the geometry, I left the Dissolve Field blank.  The result did not work for me because it created a single output polygon with one overall summed noise_value.

I've run out of ideas, and am looking for advice.

Comment: You should take a look at the dissolve tool

Comment: If you want more than one polygon after a dissolve, I'm fairly certain you need to select something in the Dissolve field.

Comment: Add geometry attributes, centroid. Concatenate them into single text field. Apply dissolve on this field. Consider rounding coordinates using something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091

Comment: @FelixIP, perfect!  Calculating the centroid is a great way to do a geometry dissolve.  In my dissolve on the centroid, I used noise_value as the statistics field with statistics_type = SUM.  The result was just what I was looking for.  If you want to reform your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.