# Finding internal angles of polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, angles

I'm working on ArcMap 10.3.1. I'd like to retrieve the values of all internal angles of each polygon of a shapefile, and return them as follows:

- either concatenated on a new field;
- or on a table;
- or as a new points shapefile, in which each point corresponds to a vertex of each of the original polygons, with an attribute for "angle".

Whichever way I get the values for the angles is fine.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  Unless there is already something at ArcGIS Code Sharing I think you will need to use ArcPy.   For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: I don't think there's an *out-of-the-box* solution for this, you'll need to script this task.. do you have any experience in arcpy or ArcObjects?

Answer (score 4):

This will do some work for polygons not sharing edges:

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("PGON", "./vertices.shp", "ALL")
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management("vertices", "Shape")
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management("PGON", "./singleLine.shp")
arcpy.SplitLine_management("singleLine", "/splits.shp")
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("splits", "LINE_BEARING")
```

Name your vertices and [assign their names to fromNode and toNode fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091) in splits and transfer line bearings to vertices table using join with relevant fields. Vertices below are labelled by in/out bearings:
[image]

This field calculator expression computes internal angles:

```
def internalA (fr,to):
 external=180-fr+to
 if external<0:external+=360
 if external>360:external-=360
 return external
 #--------------
internalA ( !fromB!, !toB! )
```

[image]