# Detecting building footprints orthogonality using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, rooftop-building

I have a number of buildings vector data from OSM and I am trying to automatically differentiate those buildings which aren't orthogonal in its edges from those that are and then calculate the error angle +/- that doesn't make it orthogonal. The error angle values will be saved as a new field (those with true orthogonality get an error angle of 0.0 as its field value).

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap 10?

Comment: Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281367/finding-internal-angles-of-polygons-using-arcgis-desktop?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that @FelixIP . I will take a look.