# Iterating through pair of points to create lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a table with ~12000 rows like:

```
NOMBRE     LAT     LONG      FECHA                INT
AL011900    15  -42.1   1900-08-27T00:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.2    -43.4   1900-08-27T06:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.3    -44.7   1900-08-27T12:00:00Z    18.0054
AL011900    15.4    -45.6   1900-08-27T18:00:00Z    18.0054
AL021900    19  -59.3   1900-09-13T12:00:00Z    33.4386
AL021900    19.5    -60 1900-09-13T18:00:00Z    36.0108
AL021900    20  -60.6   1900-09-14T00:00:00Z    38.583
AL041905    36.3    -48.6   1905-10-10T18:00:00Z    46.2996
AL041905    37.9    -47.9   1905-10-11T00:00:00Z    43.7274
AL041905    39.6    -47.1   1905-10-11T06:00:00Z    41.1552
AL041905    41  -46 1905-10-11T12:00:00Z    41.1552
```

*Fecha* is "date time" and the table is already sorted using it.

I will like to create lines between sequential points per each *NOMBRE*, keeping in the attribute of each line the *INT* values of the first point of each line. Please note that there are several *INT* per *NOMBRE* and that's the reason why I need to create lines for each consecutive pair of points.

That will be: the line from point 1 to point 2 will have the *INT* attribute of point 1. The line from point 2 to point 3 will have the *INT* value of point 2. And so on for each of the *NOMBRE*.

Comment: Convert points to line using nombre field as line id. Split line at vertices. Transfer from node attribute using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. These comments should be edits, to the question itself.

Comment: Further to @Vince's comment, please [edit] your post with the information you've added in the comments. In addition, if you're using ArcPy, then it would be better to show arcpy code rather than R code.

Comment: please ask questions for either QGIS or ArcGIS (or another software). If needed you can ask several questions for the different softwares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With arcpy you can do:

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Change. Input table need to be here
table = r'nombre' #Change
fields = ['NOMBRE','LAT','LONG_','FECHA','INT_'] #Change to match your field names
out_fc = r'nombrelines' #Output fc, will be created in script
epsg = 4326 #Change to match the epsg of your coordinate system

#Create polyline fc and add fields
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name=out_fc, geometry_type='POLYLINE', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(epsg))
for field in [('NOMBRE','TEXT'),('INT','DOUBLE')]:
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=out_fc, field_name=field[0], field_type=field[1])

#List all rows in table
all_rows = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,fields)]
all_rows = sorted(all_rows,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[3])) #Sort by nombre and fecha

#Insert rows
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_fc,['NOMBRE','INT','SHAPE@'])
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in all_rows: #Group togehter rows by nombre using defaultdict
    d[row[0]].append(row[1:])
for k,v in d.iteritems(): #d.items() in py3/ArcGIS Pro
    for pair in zip(v,v[1:]):
        array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(pair[0][0],pair[0][1]),arcpy.Point(pair[1][0],pair[1][1])])
        polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array,arcpy.SpatialReference(epsg))
        icur.insertRow((k,pair[0][-1],polyline))
del icur
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is an issue somewhere when putting together the coordinates because I get the wrong location of the lines. I think LONG is being plotted as LAT and viceversa. Can you please double check that? Line with vertices that should be  LONG -33, LAT 7 is displayed as LONG 7 , LAT -33

Comment: Just swap the indexes off array line to: `array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(pair[0][1],pair[0][0]),arcpy.Point(pair[1][1],pair[1][0])])`