# Obtaining Connectivity Matrix from ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

Attempting to extract a binary connectivity matrix from network dataset created from river network shapefile.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Graph below has 44 nodes and 43 edges. I used technique described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assign-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-a-polyline/125091#125091) to [Assigning point IDs to respective start and end attributes of polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090) to assign from node index (fi) and to node index (ti) to its' edges:

[image]

After that:

- create 2 point layers using fi,ti and ti,fi accordingly as XY fields and merged them;
- Converted points to raster and replaced NO DATA with zeros

[image]

Convert this raster to points to get your table.