# Selecting Deficient Water Mains

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-water-utilities

ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0 - all extensions

I have a dataset showing Water Mains (lines) for an area. I have been tasked with finding water mains that go from a given diameter to a smaller diameter, and back to a larger diameter.

For example: An 8" water main that links into a 6" water main, which then links back into an 8".

Ideally I would want to select just the 6" water main in the example but I'm unsure how to go about this. Another problem I think I might run into is that the water main lines are made up of many small segments. For example a 40 foot line is actually 8 different 5" segments.

I'm unsure whether I can use a tool for this, definition query, or write a Python script which I'm not very good with.

Comment: Does the attribute table for the water main have a unique identifier for each main and segment (e.g. main A, segment #1, #2, #3...)

Comment: @smiller The attribute table only has unique identifiers for the segments. There is no "Main A" , just segment #1, #2, #3 ..  which makes this really tough because there are 7,000+ segments

Comment: Are the links sequential? e.g. would you follow segment 1 to segment 2, or could it jump around numerically?

Comment: @smiller The segments unique identifiers are not always sequential. I have found a few Mains where the segments are sequential but for the most part - no they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

[image]

We want the 3 inch pipe.

Basic work flow:

1. Dissolve tool by diameter to connect segments.

[image]

2. Spatial join dissolved lines to themselves, one to many. Keep your diameter fields.

[image]

3. Copy/Paste spatial join layer in the table of contents. Rename one layer `LessThan` and one layer `GreaterThan`.

[image]

4. Apply the following Definition Query to the `LessThan` layer: `DIAMETER < DIAMETER_1`. These will be your pipes with a diameter less than at least one of its neighbor's diameter.
5. Apply the following Definition Query to the `GreaterThan` layer: `DIAMETER > DIAMETER_1`. These will be your pipes with a diameter greater than at least one of its neighbor's diameter.

[image]

[image]

6. Select by location -> `LessThan` identical to `Greater Than`. These pipes have a diameter that is smaller than at least one of its neighbors and a diameter that is greater than at least one of its neighbors. We're not interested in these.

[image]

7. Switch selection on your `LessThan` Layer. These are the pipes with a diameter less than all its neighbors' diameters.

[image]

8. Select By Location your original lines which share a line segment to your selected `LessThan` lines. These are the pipes you're interested in.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay so I made it to Step 8 and before I continue I just need a little bit of clarification. On Step 8 I'm doing a second Select by Location - is my input the selection from Step 7? If so, in Step 7 should I have created a feature class from selection?

Comment: @brice.f By input I mean your starting lines; the lines with insignificant sections you're trying to identify. In my pictures it would be `TestLines`. I've changed `input` to `original` in my answer for clarity.

Comment: This worked fantastically. I couldn't have done this without your help.

Comment: Locating diameter conflicts is standard procedure. It's enough to compute from and to nodes, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assigning-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-polyline/125091#125091 and summarise diameters or areas of incoming and outgoing pipes. Works for real life pipe networks. The one you show is ideal, non-existing one.