# Selecting all connecting lines until dead-ends using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I currently have a layer with line segments and points, and I'd like to select all connected line segments from a point to dead ends.

I've tried looking into create routes, traces and dangles, however these all seem overly complex for what I am trying to achieve (essentially some sort of logic which keep selecting connected lines then terminates when no connection are found. Unfortunately I don't have access to any network analysis packages, I only have ye old' ArcMap 10.6.

I've attached what I would envision the output to look like. Note the red dotted outline isn't required. Any pointers would be helpful, it seems so simple but yet I can't find anything!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps start with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assigning-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-polyline/125091#125091 after generating end points and removal of identical.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange ! It's been a while since I did these things, but what you're describing is usually applied to stream dynamics. ArcMap has a LOT of hydrological tools aimed at mapping such things. Search for 'stream networks' - I think It will bring you closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks FelixIP and @jonatr, I will have a look there, thank you very much for your reply!