# Selecting lines between two points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, select, route

I have two layers: One representing intersections in a city; and the other representing the road network. As shown below, I'd like the ability to select road segments provided two intersections. That is, if I'm told the intersections are 1st & 2nd street and 2nd & 3rd street, I want that portion of the road network between the two accessible using a select by attributes expression.

[image: Given 2 intersections (red and blue points), only the yellow segment should be highlighted using a select by attributes]

So far I've tried spatial joins and feature vertices to points on my road feature class, but I haven't had any luck with either tool.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assigning-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-polyline-using-arc/125091#125091

Comment: Can you split the road network line at each intersection, then assign an attribute based on which intersections they touch?