# Joining attributes of two points from line using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, vector, spatial-join

I have layers of lines connected at two points.

How can I extract information from two points on a line feature with ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assigning-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-polyline-using-arc/125091#125091

Comment: i want for each of the liness between each 2 consecutive points keep the attibutes of the three (the line segment, point 1 and point 2)in my line layer.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

1. Feature Vertices To Points (extract start vertices)
2. Select By Location with vertices layer and your point layer
3. Export selection
4. Spatial join to the line layer

repeat for end vertices

Comment: Thanks you so much !!! i appreciate

Comment: its sounds good