# Generate table of intersecting lines for the same feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a Polyline feature class.
For each feature in the Fc...I want the list of all the connecting lines(A table).
For Example For Feature 17686 Connecting Id are : 17688 & 17684.
For Reference :
[image]

Comment: See these links for Select by Location: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm  and this link for exporting selected records in an attribute table: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/export-selected-records-from-a-table.htm

Comment: I have seen that it is not solving my purpose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derive lines end points, delete spatially identical, name points and [transfer their attributes to lines table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/assigning-point-ids-to-respective-start-and-end-attributes-of-polyline-using-arc/125091#125091):

[image]
[image]

Export lines table to 2 identical stand-alone table in **GDB**, e.g. ABC and CBA and Make Query Table No1:

[image]

Repeat to create Query Table No2 and 3, using:

```
ABC.ton = BCA.fromn
and
ABC.ton = BCA.ton
```

You'll need to export all query tables and concatenate them. Table below shows all lines connected to line 612, compare it with 1st picture:

[image]

This hectic workflow can be replaced by tiny field calculator expression:

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
dF,dT=defaultdict(list),defaultdict(list)
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("LINKS",("LINKNO" , "fromn" , "ton"))
for i,f,t in tbl:
 dF[f]+=[str(i)]; dF[t]+=[str(i)]
 dT[t]+=[str(i)]; dT[f]+=[str(i)]

def getConnected(i,f,t):
 bigList = set(dF[f]+dT[t])
 bigList.remove(str(i))
 return ','.join(list(bigList))
#-----
getConnected( !LINKNO!, !fromn! , !ton! )
```

[image]

Use python, I think there is a need for one more query table if there are more than one line going out from FromNode:(