# Automatically selecting main rivers of very branched river network using Arc Hydro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, arc-hydro, stream-order

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and Arc Hydro.

Is there any way to automatically select the main rivers of a very branched river network?

Comment: Related to this recent question I think: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154892/ There's probably no automatic selection as this is basically an analysis. You'll run into an issue wherever two segments of the same order come together - the downstream segment will be the same order, but determining which of the upstreams is 'main' requires further analysis of total upstream length or some other criteria. Not very familiar with the hydro tools. Seems like it would be derived from accumulated flow or total length. I see several tools mentioned for main/longest path.

Comment: What is your definition of main river?